# output extra column when concatenating two .csv files

Tags: python, pandas

Im am fairly new using pandas but I was able to concatenate two .csv files
but when Im am outputting it there seems to be an extra column that I do not know where it is coming from.

.csv file 1

```
Tweet,Month,Day,Year
Hello World,6,2,2013
I want ice-cream!,7,23,2013
Friends will be friends,9,30,2017
Done with school,12,12,2017
```

.csv file 2

```
Month,Day,Year,Hour,Tweet
January,2,2015,12,Happy New Year
March,21,2016,7,Today is my final
May,30,2017,23,Summer is about to begin
July,15,2018,11,Ocean is still cold
```

My code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#from datetime import *
import datetime

table1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv', parse_dates={'Date':['Year', 
'Month','Day']})
table2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv', parse_dates={'Date':['Year', 
'Month','Day']})
finaldf = (pd.concat([table1, table2[['Date', 
'Tweet']]]).sort_values('Date', ascending=False))
finaldf['Date'] = finaldf['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y')
print(finaldf)
finaldf.to_csv('combined.csv', index=False)
```

when you run my code, it is outputting a first column with numbers, how would you remove this? and why is does it appear? Image at the bottom (output)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29f31.png)

Comment: You might want to try: `finaldf.reset_index(drop = True)`

Comment: Thank you, how did this happen? (the extra column being there)

Answer (score 0):

Table1 has index (0,1,2,3).
Table2 has index (0,1,2,3).
So when you concatenate the two tables you get indexes (0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3).

When you sort them their order changes.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The extra columns are just the indices of `table1` and `table2`.

You can't have a dataframe without an index. What you can do is reset the counting with `final_df.reset_index(drop=True)`